How to change setup language when using Mosyle to manage Mac?
MacBook Air M2 running macOS Sonoma was initially setup using “Français (Canada)” language (during initial setup).
Now, when Mac is factory reset using Mosyle, language selection step is no longer displayed and, therefore, I have no way to change setup language to English.
According to Mosyle docs:

As part of this process, the previously selected language and region is applied.

Is there a way round this?

You can't change the language in the OS after the setup?  If not, your Mosyle admin probably needs to open that up.  Otherwise, remove Mosyle and reactivate.

Hey @MarcWilson, thanks for helping out… yes I can but issue is when we factory reset Macs to hand them over to another user, setup is in the wrong language even if language is changed using “System Preferences”.

For some reason, language selection step is only shown first time Mac is setup… not after resets.

I don't mean to be US-centric, but if it's only changeable later, I'd set them up in English and let the user change it.
